# php искажение кириллицы при добавлении в файл

Tags: php, кириллица, json-encode

В php скрипт методом post передается подобный json объект: `{"name":"Иван", "surname":"Иванов"}`.
Далее необходимо данный объект записать в обычный текстовый файл. При попытке реализовать это так:

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($obj), FILE_APPEND);
```

В файл вместо кириллицы заносится подобный текст:

> \u0418\u0432\u0430

Решить данную проблему получилось абсолютно неэлегантным способом:

```
    $file = "file.txt";
    $str = '{';
    foreach($obj as $key=>$val) {
        $str.='"'.$key.'":'.'"'.$val.'",'; 
    }
    $str = preg_replace("/.$/","",$str);
    $str .= "}\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $str, FILE_APPEND);
```

Объект должен быть записан в файл именно с фигурными скобками. 
Все файлы имеют кодировку UTF8 без BOM. Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть есть какой-то более красивый и лаконичный способ справиться с данной задачей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте специальный флаг функции `json_encode()` (смори второй пример [в документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php))

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое